# Foreign key and cascade problems on delete Symfony4

Tags: symfony

An entity project can have many personnages, many chapitres, one highConcept for each project. And the user can have many projects. Then, when I want to remove a project I have this error message :

> An exception occurred while executing 'DELETE FROM projets WHERE id = ?'  with params [2]:
>
> SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1451 Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails (`writtle`.`personnages`, CONSTRAINT `FK_286738A6C18272` FOREIGN KEY (`projet_id`) REFERENCES `projets` (`id`))

this is my entities:

Personnages Entity

```php
/**
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="App\Entity\Chapitre", mappedBy="personnages")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="projet_id", referencedColumnName="id", onDelete="CASCADE")
     */
    private $chapitres;

  /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="App\Entity\Projets", inversedBy="personnages")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="projet_id", referencedColumnName="id", onDelete="CASCADE")
     */
    private $projet;
```

Projet entity

```php
/**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="App\Entity\User", inversedBy="projets")
     * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="user_id", referencedColumnName="id")
     */
    private $user;

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="App\Entity\Personnages", mappedBy="projet")

     */
    private $personnages;

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="App\Entity\Chapitre", mappedBy="projet", cascade={"remove"})
     * @ORM\joinColumn(onDelete="SET NULL")
     */
    private $chapitres;
```

Chapitre entity

```php
 /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="App\Entity\Projets", inversedBy="chapitres")
     */
    private $projet;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="App\Entity\Personnages", inversedBy="chapitres")
     */
    private $personnages;
```

HighConcept

```php
/**
     * @ORM\OneToOne(targetEntity="App\Entity\Projets", cascade={"persist", "remove"})
     */
    private $projet;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="App\Entity\User", inversedBy="highconcepts")
     */
    private $user;
```

User entity

```php
/**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="App\Entity\Projets", mappedBy="user")
     */
    private $projets;

    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="App\Entity\Highconcept", mappedBy="user")
     */
    private $highconcepts;
```

I don't know how I can relate this, I tried some things like `JoinColumn` `ondelete` `cascade`...
 I see some topics, but I think I use it correctly.

Comment: when deleting your project, do you want all the related entities to be deleted as  well ?

Comment: Thanks for your anwser, Yeah if a user click on delete all related entitites must be deleted

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Considering that you want to remove all the entities contained in your project I suggest you to use the `orphanRemoval` option as explained in the [Doc](https://www.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/2.6/reference/working-with-associations.html#orphan-removal).

> There is another concept of cascading that is relevant only when removing entities from collections. If an Entity of type A contains references to privately owned Entities B then if the reference from A to B is removed the entity B should also be removed, because it is not used anymore.

making the members of your entity look like:

```php
/**
* @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="App\Entity\Personnages", mappedBy="projet", orphanRemoval=true)
*/
private $personnages;
```

Comment: Thanks ! And I must add this on each children of project that's it ?

Comment: just on the `project` side as it's the owner of the relation.